# How can I control the main timeline in adobe animate from a function?

Tags: function, actionscript, jquery-animate, adobe

I have a main timeline with sound that streams and two characters in two seperate movie clips that have lip sync with the main timeline sound stream.

I want to be able to start and stop the two characters alone with the main timeline with a function I can call.

Anyone know how I would do that?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I assume that "*...characters alone with...*" was actually "*...characters **ALONG** with...*", right?

Comment: I am having issues with controlling characters on the main timeline.  I want to start and stop them with a function I can call on anytime from my main timeline.  basically I have all the lip sync stuff in them and the sound clip on the main timeline so when I stop the maintimeline I want to be able to make them stop as well with a function I can call on.

Comment: What kind of issues? Normally, you name them, say, **Lip1** and **Lip2**, and call **root.Lip1.play();** and **root.Lip2.play();** whenever you call **root.play();**, and same for **root.stop();**

Comment: I have a character with all the mouth shapes mapped for the audio using the lip syn automation.  Then I put the actual audio on the main timeline because there was issues leaving it in the characters movie clip.  So I just made the one in the character a guide layer so it wouldn't export.  Now I want to start stop the characters timeline with a function from the main timeline.  Not sure how to code it.

Comment: I just posted in the previous comment. You name objects placed on the stage (Instance Name in the Property Inspector) then you address them via their instance names. You probably need to read this for some understanding: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html